# What is this creature/machine removing a baby from the treepod?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

In the movie *[Man of Steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_of_Steel_(film))*, Jor-El, the biological father of Kal-El AKA Superman approaches the central hub to get the [Growth Codex](http://dcextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Growth_Codex). While he was on the way to the Genesis chamber(place where Codex is saved), something with tentacles is shown there removing a baby from the tree pod.

[image]

- What is this creature/machine?
- Why is it removing the baby from the tree pod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is this creature/machine?

The birthing of Kryptonians, as we know, is no longer "natural" but is an *automated* process.

Clearly the creature/machine is just part of the handling process of the gestation of new children.

> The Genesis Chamber was fashioned on the planet Krypton to house the Growth Codex and all unborn Kryptonian gene seeds that would occupy prospective Kryptonian generations. **Aquabots** were utilized to control and preserve the Genesis Chamber so that no Kryptonian would ever enter or interfere with the birthing procedure.
>
> <sup>[Wikia](http://dcextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Genesis_Chamber)</sup>

---

> Why is it removing the baby from the tree pod?

Well, we don't know precisely but, *from the image*, it seems that the baby is full term and ready to be "born".

Essentially, it seems likely that that this baby is "ripe" and is being removed from the Genesis process to be handed to it's new parents.